# Google Groups Directory API - Add user to group raises error - PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I have been trying to add members to my google apps group. I am trying with following code but it raises error. Don't know what is doing wrong.

```
include_once 'api-client/autoload.php';

$clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';

$serviceAccountName = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com';

$delegatedAdmin = 'superadmin@domain.com';

$keyFile = 'mw-gxxxxxxxx.p12';

$appName = 'Example App';

$scopes = array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group'
);

$creds = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $serviceAccountName,
    $scopes,
    file_get_contents($keyFile)
);

$creds->sub = $delegatedAdmin;

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName($appName);
$client->setClientId($clientId);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($creds);

$dir = new Google_Service_Directory($client);


 $member = new Google_Service_Directory_Member(array('name@domain.com',
                        'kind' => 'admin#directory#member',
                        'role' => 'MEMBER',
                        'type' => 'USER'));

$list = $dir->members->insert('01tuee7433xxxxx', $member);
```

## **The error:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 
'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/01tuee7433v8xwz/members: (400) Missing required field: memberKey'
```

Comment: `Missing required field: memberKey`

Comment: where and how to put that?

Comment: I am using the same code. But it gives me  this error - Call to undefined method Google_Client::setAssertionCredentials()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add 'email' in the $member object, as it is a required field for the POST request to add a new member in the specified group.

```
$member = new Google_Service_Directory_Member(array('email' => 'name@domain.com',
                        'kind' => 'admin#directory#member',
                        'role' => 'MEMBER',
                        'type' => 'USER'));
```

You can refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members#create_member).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tried whole hour trying to figure out what is missing. Now wondering how I missed that. :)

Comment: HI MECHANICWEB  and KRR. I am using the same code. But it gives me this error - Call to undefined method Google_Client::setAssertionCredentials()

Comment: how to check if member email is already exists in the groups?